# How to parse this string in the best way

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have several strings that looks like this one:

```
\r\n\t\StaticWord1:\r\n\t\t2014-05-20 11:03\r\n\t\StaticWord2\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWordC WordD\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t
```

I would like to get the date (`2014-05-20 11:03` in my example - but will vary), `Word C` and `D`. (Both `C` and `D` can be any sequence of letters).

How would I parse this as efficient as possible? I was thinking about using the `String.Replace` method but I think a regex would be better? (C#)

Comment: How does your StaticWords and Word C and D differ?

Comment: WordC and WordD could be any word. StaticWord1 and StaticWord2 are always the same word.

Comment: Is there really a `\S` in the string, or is it a `\\S`?

Comment: You're right. The latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input = @"\r\n\t\StaticWord1:\r\n\t\t2014-05-20 11:03\r\n\t\StaticWord2\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWordC WordD\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t"; 

string pattern = @"(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})(?:[\\r\\n\\t]*StaticWord2[\\r\\n\\t]*)(\w+)\s(\w+)";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

Then to get the values:

```
match.Groups[1].Value;  // date-time
match.Groups[2].Value;  // WordC
match.Groups[3].Value;  // WordD
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this capture string :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input,  @"(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d)",
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(key, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Your result is here
}
```

Comment: Your general idea(using regular expressions for parsing) is fine(scored) but please be aware that some systems may produce date value that is not possible to be parsed to DateTime in the .NET (example: SAP may deliver date like this "0000-00-00", similar problem may happen with date comming form MySQL DB("0000-00-00 00:00:00"), ...). So, be aware what you are trying to parse and make sure that you handle narrow cases correctly. Mdc didn't specify source of this date and using DateTime.ParseExact by default may not be the best idea...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best way but you can use a split like in this msdn example :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

With this example you can easily create an array like in the example and split your string with \t \n \r ... and with a loop get all your words :

```
class TestStringSplit
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { '\r', '\n', '\t' };

        string text = "\r\n\t\StaticWord1:\r\n\t\t2014-05-20 11:03\r\n\t\StaticWord2\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWordC WordD\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t";
        System.Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

        string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```